# Insert datetime

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, datetime, annotations

I am having a base class for POSTS like this

```
public partial class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
}
```

I want to make that `PostDate` always had a value when record was creates instead of specifying it in form. Maybe you guys know some good solutions, maybe there is some annotation or something to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Set it in your constructor of the class. It will be called when you create a new instance.

```
public partial class Post
{
    public Post()
    {
      PostDate = DateTime.Now; // or DateTime.UtcNow;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Tag> Tag { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use this:

```
post.PostDate  = DateTime.UtcNow;
```

Add it when you create a new post. Or you can make it in sql when you create the table using `default`.

Answer (score 0):

I think below will help you

```
 [Required]
 [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage="Your message")]
 public DateTime? PostDate { get; set; }
```